# Excel: matching the content of cell A on cell B and replacing the text

Tags: excel, replace

My problem is the following:

I have two cells (A & B) in a excel spreadsheet.
I need to find in cell A the word(s) contained in cell B; I need then to copy the entire content of cell A in a new cell and replacing the word found with the exact content of cell B plus a tag.

Example.

**Cell A: "bla bla bla word bla bla bla"**

**Cell B: "word"**

Expected result:

**Cell C: "bla bla bla [tag]word[/tag] bla bla bla"**

At the moment I have been able to find the text contained of cell B in cell A, and to copy the entire text to a new cell if the text if found, othewise it writes "not ok":

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(B2; A2)); A2; "Not OK")
```

I hope my question is clear enough.
Thanks to everyone who will have the time and patience to help me!
Alex

Comment: In your example cell C has the same contents as cell A. Your formula should give you the expected result.

Comment: your working formula is fine,it seems i am unable to understand you completely

Comment: Sorry, I missed to insert the [tag]word[/tag]

Comment: Thanks to everyone! I'm a beginner and just started using this great forum! I hope I'll be able soon to contribute myself to the community!

Comment: Please mark "Sam" answer as accepted (you will also receive 2 points) since it solved your problem in this way this question status will be answered.(you will have a check mark in green you can see it )... Read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should be able to just use `Substitute`?

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,B1,"[Tag]"&B1&"[/Tag]")
```

Comment: Wow! That's it! Thank yo for your help! How fast you all guys are!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(B2, A2)), REPLACE(A2,FIND(B2, A2),LEN(B2),"[tag]" & B2 & "[/tag]"), "Not OK")
```

This results in:

```
bla bla bla [tag]word[/tag] bla bla bla
```